Oracle sql how to add long comment
I'm trying to execute
Comment on table TABLENAME is '';
But the content I want to use for the comment is too long, resulting in an ORA-01704: string literal too long error.
How can I store a very long string in the comment?

There really isn't a need for such a lengthy string as a comment on a table. You may be attempting to use comments for something they weren't intended for. They are meant for at most a brief description of the entity in your model. Consider instead using your own table to track whatever is you wish to record, rather than using the COMMENT statement. Then you can use a CLOB or whatever you wish.


How can I store a very long string in the comment?

The COMMENT statement has the syntax:


[...]
IS 'string'
Specify the text of the comment. Refer to "Text Literals" for a syntax description of 'string'.

Where the comment string is a text literal which has the properties:

Text literals have properties of both the CHAR and VARCHAR2 data types:

Within expressions and conditions, Oracle treats text literals as though they have the data type CHAR by comparing them using blank-padded comparison semantics.
A text literal can have a maximum length of 4000 bytes if the initialization parameter MAX_STRING_SIZE = STANDARD, and 32767 bytes if MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED. See Extended Data Types for more information.


Therefore, the comment MUST be a text literal (it cannot be an expression or a CLOB) and the maximum size of a text literal is 4000 bytes (or 32767 bytes if you are using extended string sizes).
It is impossible to store a longer string than this limit as the syntax does not allow it.
